# Bootstrap 4 validating credit card with custom messages

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 validation. How can I validate the credit card number must be numbers and must be 16 digits and show appropriate message?

I would like to show three separate messages. 1. If noting is entered, "Credit card number is required" 2. If user enters "xyz etc", then "numbers only" , 3. If user enters less than 16 numbers, then show message as ""CC must be 16 digits". How can we show multiple custom messages?

Please see the fiddle.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
  </head>
  <body class="bg-light">

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Credit card number is required
            </div>
          </div>
<hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
</form>
  <script>
  // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
</script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6p3th7zz/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle is broken because jQuery wasn't included. Add a HTML5 credit card pattern to the input, and Bootstrap 4 will display the appropriate `invalid-feedback` message...

https://jsfiddle.net/uq4rb7zy/

```
 <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" method="POST">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
         <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" required="" pattern="[0-9]{16}">
         <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Credit card number is required and must be 16 digits
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="mb-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
    </form>
```

---

***EDIT*** Bootstrap doesn't provide separate validation messages. However, you could do something like this with the **HTML5 validation API**...

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          var ele = form.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                var msg = "", reason = ele[i].validity;
                if (reason.valueMissing) {
                   msg = ele[i].getAttribute("data-value-missing");
                }
                else if (reason.patternMismatch) {
                   msg = ele[i].getAttribute("data-pattern-mismatch");
                }
                else {
                    // other reason...
                }
                ele[i].nextElementSibling.innerText=msg;
            }
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

And then on the input, add a `data-value-missing` and `data-pattern-mismatch` message...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" required="" pattern="[0-9]{16}" data-value-missing="A credit card number is required" data-pattern-mismatch="The credit card number must be 16 digits">
<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
```

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/I6WFYML9sS)

This will only provide different messages for based on [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) (eg. required vs. pattern). It isn't going to match specific reasons for pattern failure (eg. numbers vs characters).

Comment: Hi Zim, Thank you for the response. I understood that you are showing a generic message that would work for both scenarios. I would like to show threee separate messages. 1. If noting is entered, "Credit card number is required" 2. If user enters "xyz etc", then numbers only 3. If user enters only 10 numbers, then CC must be 16 digits. How can we show multiple custom messages ?

Comment: This exactly what I am looking for :) Thank you so much. SO I don't have to use Jquery validation plugin anymore.

Comment: This is very useful and looking for exactly like this sample. However, I am getting an error at below line. "ele[i].nextElementSibling.innerText=msg;"  - Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Answer (score 0):

I have this script for limit the phone number and DNI (Document identity from Spain)

```
        <script>
        // Funcion para limitar el numero de caracteres de un textarea o input
                function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres)
                {
                    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

                    if(unicode==8 || unicode==46 || unicode==13 || unicode==9 || unicode==37 || unicode==39 || unicode==38 || unicode==40)
                        return true;
                    // Si ha superado el limite de caracteres devolvemos false
                    if(contenido.length>=caracteres)
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }

        //Funcion ONLY NUMBERS
            function numbersonly(myfield, e, dec){
            var key;
            var keychar;

            if (window.event)
               key = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (e)
               key = e.which;
            else
               return true;
            keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

            // control keys
            if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || 
                (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
               return true;

            // numbers
            else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
               return true;

            // decimal point jump
            else if (dec && (keychar == "."))
               {
               myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();
               return false;
               }
            else
               return false;
        }

        $(function(){           
            if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            // If not native HTML5 support, fallback to jQuery datePicker


                $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: '-100:+0',
                    // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
                    },
                    // Localization
                    $.datepicker.regional['es']
                );
            }
        });


    </script>
```

Check the code, sure it works, then you just have to call the function in the input like this

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputDNI" placeholder="DNI" onKeyUp="return limitar(event,this.value,9)" onKeyDown="return limitar(event,this.value,9)" required>
```

Comment: Thanks Kobe. I know how to use jQuery validation but bootstrap 4 came up with new style of validation. I am just wondering if there is anyway we can leverage same for custom validation. If not, How I can plugin jQuery validation with bootstrap 4 validation ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question ... I do not know how I can help you, did you look at the bootstrap guide?

Comment: Here is the JSFiddel, I have updated my question. See if you can update your answer. https://jsfiddle.net/uq4rb7zy/