# Adding custom validation functions to bootstrap 4 validation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

So I was looking at Bootstrap 4's helper script for form validation (below). However, is it possible to add more functions to the form.checkValidity() === false? The reason I ask is because if I have a text field but I want to make sure it is only alphanumeric numbers in a text field? The script below sees this `6564654655673467*%(&^%%$` as *ok* for a text input, but it shouldn't in my case. The reason I ask is because the below script does a nice thing where if it shows an error message and you start typing, it removes the error message as you type. Furthermore, I have a function (also below) that checks if it is valid and returns true or false.

Basically I want the error messages to disappear without having to do a check if the input has is-invalid on click for each input on the form.

### Form Validation

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('js_twbs_form');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

### Name Validation Function

```
function usecaseValidation(auctionUseCase) {

  if (auctionUseCase === "") {
    document.getElementById('useCaseError').innerHTML = "Auction case cannot be empty.";
    return false;
  } else if (auctionUseCase.match(/^[\w\-\s]+$/i) == null) {
    document.getElementById('useCaseError').innerHTML = "Alphanumeric characters only.";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: traditionally bootstrap is used with jquery.validate . have you considered it?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652831/bootstrap-4-validating-credit-card-with-custom-messages/49653418#49653418